# Publish nuGet package as single file

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package, dotnet-publish

I am not sure if I am rightly thinking or not, but I was trying to create a nuget package which can be published as a single file, so that dependent nuget libraries must be bundled in single nuget package and when we add it as reference, it should not show the dependent libraries in references under the main package as well as it should not be shown in bin folder when you build the project. I want to do it using teamcity (if possible).

As an example, just like when we set a property

```
<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
```

in .csproj and then publish the application from Visual Studio, then it creates only single large file containing all libraries bundled with it. We just want the same in nuget. Is it possible?